# How is sscanf different from scanf in the following statements?

Tags: c, unix

I came across the following statement while I was going through a C program for client/server message handling in Unix.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    (void)sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&port);
}
```

It would be helpful if you can explain the above statement.

**Edit**: I don't know why people feel my question is not clear... I just wanted to know that if `scanf` takes input from keyboard then the above statement `sscanf` also does the same job indirectly. Is that correct?

Comment: If you are trying to convert a string to an int, then it can be done without those functions.

Comment: `sscanf();` = reads formatted input from a string, `scanf();` = reads formatted input from stdin

Comment: Since the definition of `buf` is not shown, there isn't much we can say.  It must be a file scope variable or a global variable; it must be a character pointer or a character array; it must be initialized with a value because the code in `main()` doesn't set it.  And given all that, there was no obvious point in storing it as a string only to convert it to an integer.  OK: the question morphed — the `main()` wrapper is gone.  We still can't see how `buf` is defined or initialized.  But the statement converts the number stored in the string (if there is one) into an integer.

Comment: Please **read documentation of standard functions** you are using. Here is one for [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: I just wanted to know that if scanf takes input from keyboard then the above statement sscanf also does the same job indirectly. Is that correct???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sscanf()` reads formatted input from a string.

`scanf()` reads formatted input from `stdin`.

So in your example `sscanf` reads from the first argument of the program and saves it in the variable `port`.

As a little example what `sscanf` does:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    
    int day;
    char str[100];

   strcpy(str, "21" );
   sscanf(str, "%d", &day);

   printf("day: %d", day);
    
   return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
day: 21
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` parses data from program input (`stdin` / "keyboard").

`sscanf()` parses data from a provided string.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` function reads data from `stdin` into the locations given by each entry in the argument list.

`sscanf()` function reads data from a string(in your case `argv[1]`) into the location given(`port` in your case)

Answer (score 1):

The **scanf()** function reads input from the standard input stream **stdin**.

The **sscanf()** function reads its input from the character string pointed to by its **first argument**.